# events not firing for "input" in chrome jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get any key events to fire on an input element with jquery.  Given the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">         


            $("#cmd").keypress(function(event) {
                alert("keypress");
                if(event.which == 13){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "update",
                        data: "key=" + key + "&cmd=" + $("#cmd").val()
                    });
                    $("#cmd").val("");
                    $("#cmd").focus();
                }
            });


    </script>
        <title>BCMD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" style="background-color: black; color: white; width:100%; height:500px;">
            <input id="cmd" type="text" style="border:0;"></input>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Nothing is firing.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: have the jQuery files loaded? Check from the NET tab from firebug. I think that might be the problem

Comment: Try surrounding your $("#cmd")... source with a $(function() { }); ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rrqK7/ firing for me in this fiddle. Have you tried the obvious and cleared your cache?

Comment: @jesse The fiddle works because you've got the fiddle set to run your code onload.  His code is not set to onload.  Set it to "no wrap (head)" to mimic his issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the $(document).ready function. Enscapsulate your Javascript in $(function() {} ); to get it to work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">         

        $(function() {
            $("#cmd").keypress(function(event) {
                alert("keypress");
                if(event.which == 13){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "update",
                        data: "key=" + key + "&cmd=" + $("#cmd").val()
                    });
                    $("#cmd").val("");
                    $("#cmd").focus();
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

JQuery requires this kind of code to be encapsulated like that to indicate it should only be run when the document has loaded.

Comment: It's not the "jquery initialization function", it's `$(document).ready`  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @kingjiv Indeed it is! Poor wording my behalf, my apologies.

Comment: That was indeed the problem.  Thanks!  Still pretty new to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the code before the `cmd` element exists.  Wrap your code in document.ready:

```
$(function(){
    // your code here
})
```

This will wait until the DOM has loaded before executing your code.